# How to prevent space trimming when importing HTML with ImportString?

Tags: import, html, character-encoding, parsing

I am importing a HTML-formatted string with

```
ImportString[string, "HTML"]
```

to properly parse all HTML-escaped characters like `&gt;` and `&nbsp;`.
However, Mathematica seems to trim all repeated spaces in the process:

```
ImportString["a   b", "HTML"]
ImportString["a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b", "HTML"]
ImportString["a&nbsp; &nbsp; b", "HTML"]
```

> ```
> a b
> a b
> a b
> ```

Can I disable this unwanted trimming of spaces while parsing a HTML-formatted string?

Comment: I was under the impression that repeated whitespace characters are trimmed by definition in HTML. My knowledge is 10 yrs out of date, so I may be misremembering it.

Comment: But how could [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) survive if this would be true?

Comment: `pre` and `code` elements preserve formatting, and likely so do a few others. But, it seems I was correct, at least as far as chrome is concerned about `p` eating white space.